# IIS 7 File Not found 404 error on IIS Home Page

Tags: iis-7

I have setup new machine with IIS 7. When I tried from `http://localhost` it shows IIS home page . When I tried the same with from remote machine `http://machinename`, I get 404 page not found error. When I pinged IIS machine, it was successful and telnet also worked. I don't know what is the issue. Could you help on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the bindings for the Default Web Site. Make sure there is set to http All Unassigned port:80 and a blank host name.

Comment: added site binding on default website, Type=http, IP=machine's ip address, port = 80, host name = empty worked

Comment: You could also add a specific binding for the host header = your machine name, or whatever else you would like to use.